# .NET access to SQL over network is faster than locally - um, why?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, sqlclient

I have an unusual issue in that one of my servers is performing better than all the others and I want to know why - this is so I can make the others work as well :-)

Here is my (simplified) scenario:
I have one SQL Server 2012 box which is our production environment - let's call this PROD. I have a .NET tool that we created that runs a few queries over and over again. If I run this tool on the server itself talking to a local database, I get response times of between 4 and 20 ms for the set of simple queries, and between 589 and 731 ms for a more complex query.

We also have another SQL Server 2012 box of the same spec - let's call this STAG. If I run the same tool on this box, connected to the PROD database (i.e. same code, same connection string etc.) I get response times of between 0 and 1 ms for the simple queries and 109 to 133ms for the more complex query, i.e. significantly better.

We have a third SQL Server 2012 box of the same spec - let's call this TEST. Again, running the same tool connecting to PROD I get response times of between 4 and 15, and 600 to 800 ms respectively.

In fact the pattern is that if I run this tool on ANY server (or client) except our STAG environment, the timings are about the same. It is just STAG that is out performing all of the other environments and I really want to know why!

If I run the queries in SSMS then they are all performant (i.e. very fast as one would expect).

So, it appears that on most boxes, accessing the database from .NET has an overhead except our STAG server, and I want ALL of our servers to have this level of performance.

Things I've checked and all appear to match:

- SQL client and server protocols and configuration
- underlying hardware (it's all running on the same vSphere infrastructure)
- .NET Framework versions
- AV version and policy applied

I'm at a loss to know what else to check - can anyone else make any suggestions?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Analyze it. I mean, *actually* analyze it, not comparing setups or assuming things should be the same. Track the network traffic with Wireshark and see the packet delays, `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`, query plans. The first thing to do is pin down whether the difference is due to the query execution in SQL Server, or the underlying network/CPU/memory infrastructure. My money's on the latter. (Virtual hardware is hardware too, and it can behave far more strangely than physical hardware.)

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you too that it is not SQL Server related as running the same queries in SSMS with the setting you mentioned above on, takes 0ms - you can't get faster than this!
Also, the fact that it is access from the STAG server to PROD being much faster tells me that it is something to do with .NET itself since other ways of querying the database are lightening fast.
I'll have a look at the wireshark stuff, but again the fact that the server talking to itself is slower than a different server also seems odd.

Comment: Using Wireshark, I can see that the sending and receiving of data for the TEST server is about 30ms slower than STAG which to me shows that the network and underlying hardware of the PROD server is not the issue - it has to be something in between the lines of code running and the messaging over the network - inside the .NET System.Data.SqlClient maybe? But isn't this just like a black box for us to use?

Comment: If by "black box" you mean something that's not only easily decompiled but has its [source online](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/ref/System.Data.SqlClient.cs/), then yes, it's a total black box. :-P However, there's little point diving in there, because I can guarantee there's no magic 30 ms delay loop in there somewhere -- it'll be sending out packets as best as it can. See if other network traffic is similarly impacted. Try doing a simple HTTP call from a simple .NET app, check software firewalling, try `netsh winsock reset` for giggles.

Comment: My point is, is that it is NOT just a 30ms delay - for a complex query the difference is 429ms on one server (the one talking to its local DB) and 80ms on the other (talking to the remote DB).
Local to local is 5 times slower than remote to local.

Comment: For a local connection, the network should not be an issue since you're not using the network at all, it goes through shared memory. (Provided you're connecting with "." or the exact server name as the hostname.) Any delays there should be immediately attributable to the hardware (that is, there's only so much CPU and memory available for your tool and SQL Server to share, which is not an issue with a remote host). As the hardware is virtual, that would still be a software issue, just not one of your software. You could eliminate .NET as the culprit by checking with a local `sqlcmd`.

Comment: I agree - I don't think the network is the issue.
I am using the exact hostname with the instance in the connection string. All of the servers have heaps of CPU and memory. When you say a local "sqlcmd" are you talking about though SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right - I have finally tracked this down and it's not great, but at least I have consistency.
We had a error in the logic of our tool that calculates the timings - we were using TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond and for some reason the Stopwatch.Frequency is different on one of our servers  **8-@**

Switching to a Stopwatch.StartNew(), then Stop() and using ElapsedMilliseconds give us the correct answer.

Thanks to Jeroen for all of your help - at least next time I have a performance issue I can take your suggestions and run with these first.